# XML encoding error, but both XML and input text encoding are utf-8 in php

Tags: php, xml, laravel, utf-8, domdocument

I'm generating a XML Dom with DomDocument in php, containing some news, with title, date, links and a description. The problem occurs on description of some news, but not on others, and both of them contains accents and cedilla.

I create the XML Dom element in UTF-8:

`$dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");`

Then, I retrieve my text from a MySQL database, which is encoded in latin-1, and after I tested the encoding with `mb_detect_encoding` it returns UTF-8.

I tried the following:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $descricao);
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', $descricao);
iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $descricao);
iconv('ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', 'UTF-8', $descricao);
mb_convert_encoding($descricao, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
mb_convert_encoding($descricao, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
mb_convert_encoding($descricao, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'); //that makes no sense, but who knows
```

Also tried changing the database encode to UTF-8, and changing the XML encode to ISO-8859-1.

This is the full method that generates the XML:

```
$informativos = Informativo::where('inf_ativo','S')->orderBy('inf_data','DESC')->take(20)->get();
$dom = new \DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$rss = $dom->createElement("rss");

$channel = $dom->createElement("channel");
$title = $dom->createElement("title", "Informativos");
$link = $dom->createElement("link", "http://example.com/informativos");

$channel->appendChild($title);
$channel->appendChild($link);

foreach ($informativos as $informativo) {
    $item = $dom->createElement("item");

    $itemTitle = $dom->createElement("title", $informativo->inf_titulo);
    $itemImage = $dom->createElement("image", "http://example.com/".$informativo->inf_ilustracao);
    $itemLink = $dom->createElement("link", "http://example.com/informativo/".$informativo->informativo_id);
    $descricao = strip_tags($informativo->inf_descricao);
    $descricao = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $descricao);
    $descricao = str_replace("&#13;", " ", $descricao);
    $descricao = substr($descricao, 0, 150).'...';
    $itemDesc = $dom->createElement("description", $descricao);
    $itemDate = $dom->createElement("pubDate", $informativo->inf_data);

    $item->appendChild($itemTitle);
    $item->appendChild($itemImage);
    $item->appendChild($itemLink);
    $item->appendChild($itemDesc);
    $item->appendChild($itemDate);

    $channel->appendChild($item);
}

$rss->appendChild($channel);

$dom->appendChild($rss);

return $dom->saveXML();
```

Here is an example of successful output:

`Segundo a instituição, número de pessoas que vivem na pobreza subiu 7,3 milhões desde 2014, atingindo 21% da população, ou 43,5 milhões de br`

And an example that gives the encoding error:

```
procuradores da Lava Jato em Curitiba, que estão sendo investigados por um&#13;
suposto acordo fraudulento com a Petrobras e o Departamento de Justi�...
```

Everything renders fine, until the problematic description text above, that gives me:

"This page contains the following errors:
error on line 118 at column 20: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Probably that `&#13;` is the problem here. Since I can't control whether or not the text have this, I need to render these special characters correctly.

**UPDATE 2019-04-12:** Found out the error on the problematic text and changed the example.

Comment: Maybe try setting the encoding with an HTTP header before output the XML? `header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: In my response headers: Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8. It's already on UTF-8. Tried your suggestion, same result.

Comment: Ok, you could try setting it to ISO 8859 instead, and adjusting your code to match. What I'm wondering is if the web server is defaulting to some value that doesn't match your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding of the database **connection** is important. Make sure that it is set to UTF-8. It is a good idea to use UTF-8 most of the time (for your fields). Character sets like `ISO-8859-1` have only a very limited amount of characters. So if a Unicode string gets encoded into them it might loose data.

The second argument of `DOMDocument::createElement()` is broken. In only encodes **some** special characters, but not `&`. To avoid problems create and append the content as an separate text node. However `DOMNode::appendChild()` returns the append node, so the `DOMElement::create*` methods can be nested and chained.

```
$data = [
  [
    'inf_titulo' => 'Foo',
    'inf_ilustracao' => 'foo.jpg',
    'informativo_id' => 42,
    'inf_descricao' => 'Some content',
    'inf_data' => 'a-date'
  ]  
];
$informativos = json_decode(json_encode($data));

function stripTagsAndTruncate($text) {
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = str_replace(["&nbsp;", "&#13;"], " ", $text);
    return substr($text, 0, 150).'...';
}

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$rss = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('rss'));
$channel = $rss->appendChild($dom->createElement("channel"));
$channel
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement("title"))
  ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("Informativos"));
$channel
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement("link"))
  ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://example.com/informativos"));

foreach ($informativos as $informativo) {
    $item = $channel->appendChild($dom->createElement("item"));

    $item
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement("title"))
      ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($informativo->inf_titulo));
    $item
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement("image"))
      ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://example.com/".$informativo->inf_ilustracao));
    $item
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement("link"))
      ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("http://example.com/informativo/".$informativo->informativo_id));
    $item
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement("description"))
      ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode(stripTagsAndTruncate($informativo->inf_descricao)));
    $item
      ->appendChild($dom->createElement("pubDate"))
      ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode($informativo->inf_data));
}
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<rss>
  <channel>
    <title>Informativos</title> 
    <link>http://example.com/informativos</link> 
    <item> 
      <title>Foo</title> 
      <image>http://example.com/foo.jpg</image> 
      <link>http://example.com/informativo/42</link> 
      <description>Some content...</description> 
      <pubDate>a-date</pubDate> 
    </item> 
  </channel> 
</rss>
```

Truncating an HTML fragment can result in broken entities and broken code points  (if you don't use a UTF-8 aware string function). Here are two approaches to solve it.

You can use PCRE in UTF-8 mode and match n entities/codepoints:

```
// have some string with HTML and entities
$text = 'Hello<b>äöü</b>&nbsp;&auml;&#13; foobar';

// strip tags and replace some specific entities with spaces
$stripped = str_replace(['&nbsp;', '&#13;'], ' ', strip_tags($text));
// match 0-10 entities or unicode codepoints
preg_match('(^(?:&[^;]+;|\\X){0,10})u', $stripped, $match);
var_dump($match[0]);
```

Output:

```
string(18) "Helloäöü &auml;"
```

However I would suggest using DOM. It can load HTML and allow to use Xpath expressions on it.

```
// have some string with HTML and entities
$text = 'Hello<b>äöü</b>&nbsp;&auml;&#13; foobar';

$document = new DOMDocument();
// force UTF-8 and load
$document->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$text);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// use xpath to fetch the first 10 characters of the text content
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('substring(//body, 1, 10)'));
```

Output:

```
string(15) "Helloäöü ä"
```

DOM in general treats all strings as UTF-8. So Codepoints are a not a problem. Xpaths `substring()` works on the text content of the first matched node. The argument are character positions (not index) so they start with 1.

DOMDocument::loadHTML() will add `html` and `body` tags and decode entities. The results will a little bit cleaner then with the PCRE approach.

Comment: I changed my code to your example, but it still have problems with "&".This text: "Os&#13;
procuradores da Lava Jato em Curitiba, que estão sendo investigados por um&#13;
suposto acordo fraudulento com a Petrobras e o Departamento de Justi�..." on line 118 still gives encoding error. But, thanks to your advice I discovered that "&#13" hidden on the text, causing the error. The � must be a "ç" cut in half by the truncate.

Comment: So the description content is an encoded HTML and and a simple PHP substring can result in incomplete entities and more important broken UTF-8 characters. Here are several ways around that.

Comment: I added two solutions for the truncate.

Comment: Loading as HTML does not interfere with the XML structure? I mean, the way it is now, I get a rss xml, and read it as a XML file, if I render as HTML won't interfere with that reading?

Comment: It is loaded as HTML and truncated before it is added to the RSS. For the XML parser it is just text content, only after the value is read from the RSS-XML is treated as an HTML fragment again. If you want it better/clearer defined use Atom. But you strip the tags from the description anyway.